# Overlapping text on tag pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[Here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegetarianism) scroll to the bottom of the page:

[image]

The word "feed" overlaps the RSS logo.

This is how it should look (biology tag):

[image]

EDIT: Now I'm seeing the overlap on every tag, even biology, which I previously had taken a screenshot where it was fine.

Comment: This looks fixed to me - are you still experiencing the overlap?

Comment: @JarrodDixon, Yes I'm still seeing the issue in Firefox and IE, not in Chrome though.

Comment: Our designers are aware of the issue - we'll have a fix out shortly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix will be pushed out in the next build, > rev 2012.4.10.2176.